# hex date from NFS tag to date and or time

Tags: android, date, datetime, nfc

I am trying to decode two hex strings and think they relate to date and time. That is I can read them back from an NFC device and they are the only byes which change and are therefore related to time in some way.
the header info is

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<InfoDump application="NFC TagInfo" version="1.12a">
  <Tag rfTechnology="Type V (ISO/IEC 15693 / Vicinity)">
    <GeneralInformation>
      <Value name="uid" description="UID">e007a0000000ba84</Value>
      <Value name="rfTechnology" description="RF technology">Type V (ISO/IEC 15693 / Vicinity)</Value>
      <Value name="manufacturer" description="Manufacturer">Texas Instruments (France)</Value>
      <Value name="dsfid" description="DSF Id">00</Value>
      <Value name="responseFlags" description="Response flags">00</Value>
      <Value name="targetTechClasses" description="Target technology classes (Android)">android.nfc.tech.NfcV,
android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</Value>
    </GeneralInformation>
    <MemoryTag>
      <GeneralInformation>
        <Value name="memorySize" description="Memory size">1952 Byte</Value>
        <Value name="blockSize" description="Block size">8 Byte</Value>
        <Value name="numberOfBlocks" description="Number of blocks">244</Value>
      </GeneralInformation>
```

date byte 1 = e4530b0e0000c06e
data byte 2 = c0b2f50093520000
some moments later
date byte 1 = aa640b0e0000c06e
data byte 2 = c0b2f50097520000
anyone have an idea what format they may be in and if they are indeed a date and or time.
Regards
Ben10

Comment: Seems you have a non-standard or outdated TI tag. The ISO15693 tags that TI currently sells are TI TagIt Standard, Plus, and Pro. All of these have 64 data blocks and not 244. To be any help we need to determine what tag product you're reading. Review the product sheets here: http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/wireless_connectivity/nfc_rfid/products.page#o4=&o7=Transponders,%20Inlays%20and%20Dies&p1507=13.56%20MHz

Comment: Hi 
Many thanks for getting back to me and for your help.
I am not sure where to go next as I don’t know what chip is inside the tag. So I have split it open and photographed the circuit board in the hope that it can shed some more light on the question. Can I upload the photos to you somehow on this site?
Regards
Ben10

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1jmauzwsynx1rym/AADsJdgugHjd2Rw8OYqZRhnHa?dl=0 Hello. I have put the images in dropbox as I cant upload them to this site as I need more reputation points. Regards Ben10

Answer (score 0):

It looks very much like the TI tag used in a certain glucose sensor... The strings you are trying to decode don't relate to date/time. That device loops for 15 days. Maintains two circular buffer of records... A bit longish to go into details here.

Comment: Hi Pierre, many thanks for the info. I am a fair way in now with my project to build an app for my device on the phone.